# Creating new registry key with proper encoding

Tags: c++, unicode, character-encoding, registry, registrykey

Im trying to create a new key in HKCU with help of [this answer from cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/196897/):

```
HKEY hkey;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hkey);
const LPCSTR program = "program";
const wchar_t* path = L"(C:\\Users\\Desktop\\wallpaper.jpg)";
RegSetValueEx(hkey, LPCWSTR(program), 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)path, wcslen(path));
RegCloseKey(hkey);
```

But it creates a key with a weird `name` and incomplete `data`. This is the img of the result[image].
My second attempt was this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265159/trying-to-create-a-value-in-registry-c-regsetvalueex):

```
HKEY key;
const char* path = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\wallpaper.jpg";
RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), &key);
RegSetValueEx(key, TEXT("value_name"), 0, REG_SZ, LPBYTE(path), sizeof path * sizeof(char));
RegCloseKey(key);
```

It creates a key with correct `name` but a weird `data`, [image: img]. What is the reason of creating a key with such characters or incomplete data ? How should i resolve this ? The   key's `data` is going to be a string. For example:

```
Name    | Type   | Data
KeyName | REG_SZ | c:\user\...
```

---

**UPDATE:[Solved]**

By changing `Character Set` in project properties to `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`And this one will do the trick:

```
HKEY key; 
const char* path = R"("C:\Users\Desktop\program.bat")";
RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), &key);
RegSetValueEx(key, TEXT("value_name"), 0, REG_SZ, LPBYTE(path), strlen(path));
RegCloseKey(key);
```

***I have edited the question for many times, Its much clearer and its not duplicate now. Can you guys reopen it and upvote the question? I have reached my question limit in my 2nd question. Its so cruel.***

Comment: Ok i found it. I changed `Character Set` in project properties to `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`.

Comment: The weird character problem is solved now, But the incomplete `data`(it is not setting complete path) and quoted string data(how you add quotes?) problem still persist.

Comment: If you need to cast your strings to get the compiler to accept them, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: You are mixing ANSI and Unicode in the same code, and doing so incorrectly. Don't do that. Pick one or the other. And you are misusing `sizeof`. Your last parameter of `RegSetValueEx()` is wrong, read the documentation. `const char *path = ...; RegSetValueExA(key, "value_name", 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)path, strlen(path));` or `const wchar_t* path = ...; RegSetValueExW(hkey, L"value_name", 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)path, wcslen(path) * sizeof(wchar_t));` And you should not be using `RegOpenKey()` at all, use `RegOpenKeyEx()` instead